copy table from one workbook to another using vba
I have a table in wb1, I want to be able to copy this table then paste it to another sheet in wb2 but I want to make it more dynamic so that instead of just selecting the table, my code goes through the column names then copies each column using the name then paste it in the other worksheet. Here is my code
'get column names from table "Table1"
Dim TblHeadings() As String
Dim z As Variant
Dim i As Integer
i = -1
For Each z In Rows(2).Cells
    If z.Value = "" Then Exit For
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve TblHeadings(i) As String
    TblHeadings(i) = z.Value
Next z

'copy columns with headers from previous loop
Dim a As Range, w
With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    For Each a In z
        If w Is Nothing Then
            Set w = .ListColumns(a).Range
        Else
            Set w = Union(w, .ListColumns(a).Range)
        End If
    Next
End With

w.Select
Selection.Copy


Table1 starts on B2. How do I modify Rows(2).Cells to start on B2? Currently it starts on B1 which is empty so my loop exits? Does the rest of this code look okay?
Edit: to answer why I am doing it this way is because in another part of the code I am clearing content from wb2 table2. If I do it this way; copy and paste it as values over table2, the table goes away and it just paste as values. I want the table2 format to remain as a table. There may be a better way to do this?
wb2Sheet1.Activate
Range("Table2").Select
Selection.ClearContents

With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   .Range.Copy
End with

wb2.Activate
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


For Each z In Rows(2).Cells(2).Resize(1,1000).Cells would be a quick fix

Is there a particular reason you need to copy the table in that manner? The varible w equals to Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.

Re Does the rest of this code look okay Short answer: No.  The posted code (once fixed) does nothing mre  than simply copying the whole table would do.  By more dynamic do you mean you might want to ommit some columns, or reorder some columns?

I would probably do something like this.  The column heading array is just overhead unless you have a large number of columns to copy.
Sub Tester()

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook, loSource As ListObject, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lc As ListColumn, destHeaders As Range, c As Range, loDest As ListObject
    
    'set up the source and destination listobjects
    '  (on the same sheet for my testing...)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set loSource = .ListObjects("Table1")
        Set loDest = .ListObjects("Table2")
    End With
    
    'clear the destination table
    loDest.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For Each c In loDest.HeaderRowRange.Cells
        Set lc = Nothing 'clear this first
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore if no matching column
        Set lc = loSource.ListColumns(c.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring error
        If Not lc Is Nothing Then  'got a match
            lc.DataBodyRange.Copy c.Offset(1)
        Else
            'flag no match
            Debug.Print "No source list column for '" & c.Value & "'"
        End If
    Next c
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub

EDIT: If you just want to replace a table with a copy of another table you can do something like this.
    Dim loA As ListObject, loB As ListObject, rngB As Range
    
    Set loA = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableA")
    Set loB = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableB")
    
    Set rngB = loB.Range 'remember where the table was
    loB.Delete 'delete the destination table
    
    Set rngB = rngB.Cells(1).Resize(loA.Range.Rows.Count, loA.Range.Columns.Count)
    loA.Range.Copy rngB.Cells(1)    'copy the table
    rngB.ListObject.Name = "TableB" 'rename the copy


Hi Tim, does your code only copy a column if the header is matching? Otherwise it wont? The reason why I wanted to go column by column is because incase the columns in the source change, I want it to still be copied into the destination tab.

It only copies columns where the name matches a column in the source table.  Isn't that what your posted code was for?  I though you only wanted a subset of the source table columns.

no I want all columns because the columns in the source table could change. I want the updated version if that does happen.

So why not just copy/paste the whole table?

I tried to do that. See my edit in the post with the code I used and the issue I had.

See my edit above.

That's exactly what I needed. Thanks alot!
